# hbase put to replace existing column value

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I want to replace content of a column in a row using put but it is adding newer version of data. Tried adding time stamp but still a new value with different version is getting created.
Any ideas to replace content on same version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you have used the right timestamp value?

I have made an example for you(in hbase shell):

At first, we create a table named `tmp1` with one column family named `f1`, which can has three versions for each cell:

```
hbase(main):005:0> create 'tmp1', {NAME => 'f1', VERSIONS => 3}
0 row(s) in 1.1160 seconds
```

Next, we put one row with value `v1` into the table:

```
hbase(main):007:0> put 'tmp1', 'r1', 'f1:c1', 'v1', 1
0 row(s) in 0.0860 seconds
hbase(main):008:0> scan 'tmp1'
    ROW                                            COLUMN+CELL
    r1                                            column=f1:c1, timestamp=1, value=v1
1 row(s) in 0.0390 seconds
```

Then, we do another `put` with the same rowkey `r1`, column name `f1:c1` and timestamp `1`, but with a different value `v2`:

```
hbase(main):009:0> put 'tmp1', 'r1', 'f1:c1', 'v2', 1
0 row(s) in 0.0060 seconds

hbase(main):008:0> scan 'tmp1'
    ROW                                            COLUMN+CELL
    r1                                            column=f1:c1, timestamp=1, value=v2
```

As you can see, the cell has been replaced with the new value `v2`.

Comment: Thank you guys .. problem was with timestamp.. i had to use same time stamp as it is there in a row.. it has replaced column value now..

Answer (score 1):

Straight out of the HBase [documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/book/versions.html):

```
Put put = new Put( Bytes.toBytes(row)); 
long explicitTimeInMs = 555; // just an example
put.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("attr1"), explicitTimeInMs, Bytes.toBytes(data));
htable.put(put);
```